# error when upgrading to version 9 of ABCpdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abcpdf

I've recently upgraded to ABCPdf version 9, and now get this error:

> ABCpdf 32-bit core engine version 9102 is not compatible with ABCpdf .NET version 9.0.0.5.

Seems like there must be a rogue dll floating around. Any one know what that DLL might be called? Or point me in the right direction?

At the moment I can't find any DLL that seems to be the wrong version...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Generally, people usually go even further in removing fluff. (Think "I'm a newbie", "I've been searching for hours", "I've been wracking my brain on this for $TIME" etc.)

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I have also come across the same issue today..

Comment: @Jay the way I ended up fixing it was to uninstall and upgrade to the latest version. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JohnSaunders and @ millimoose. Thanks I'll keep that in mind for future questions! (apologies about the late reply)

Comment: @Ev. Thanks for the update.Fixed the issue in other way, The core engines in installation folder appeared to be old version(though I have made the content updated version and set copy always on build to bin), so I have added the core engines to the deployment project and packed which then the installation folder is with newer version and solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are details of the DLLs involved in the Manual Installation section of the documentation.

The core engine DLLs are called ABCpdf9-32.dll and ABCpdf9-64.dll. The former contains 32 bit code. The latter contains 64 bit code. There is another DLL called ABCpdf.dll which is the main managed assembly.

The error indicates that the these DLLs do not match up. That you've got, as you surmise, a rogue DLL floating about. If you get properties on your DLLs you should be able to see the version and work out what is what.

However at a guess I would suggest that you have the new ABCpdf DLL installed in the GAC but that you have previously copied some of the DLLs to the bin folder of your project. Remove those copied DLLs and it should just work.